# Windows: lookup DNS being used by router without accessing it

Tags: windows, networking

ok I can do this easily on Mac:

```
networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
```

How do I do this on Windows? `ipconfig /all` and `nslookup google.com` only show the router ip as DNS gateway but not the DNS **being used by the router** (either provided by ISP or static as 8.8.8.8, etc.).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The router ip IS the "real" DNS server being used, if you have "obtain DNS server address
automatically" set under your IPV4 properties. Change that to specific DNS server
ip's, and those will be shown by the ipconfig command instead.

Comment: Rephrased the question...